# Передать данные при помощи javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Доброго времени суток. Задача такая. 
есть некое поле ввода

Под ним есть ссылка

```
<a class="..." href="php.php?id=ZZZ" >php</a>
```

Вопрос, как при помощи onclick="ZZZ()" передать текст из поля ввода в адрес. 
То есть, человек пишет слово в поле, например "Праздник", а затем жмёт на ссылку и его переводит по ссылке на страницу php.php?id=Праздник

Приношу свои извинения, если данный вопрос оскорбил глаза про. Я только начал разбираться в javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Без jquery, я бы сделал так:

```js
document.getElementById('pole_vvoda').onkeyup = function() {
  document.getElementById('link').href = "url.php?id=" + this.value;
}
```

```html
<input id="pole_vvoda" type="text" />
<a href="404.php либо url.php?id=default_value" id="link">Туда</a>
```

[Пример на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guqLeaLg/1/)

Сам javascript тоже знать полезно.

Comment: jsfiddle требовался на ХК, здесь же есть свой "мини-jsfiddle" - при создании/редактирования вопроса/ответа выбираем листок со стрелками (фрагмент кода Control+M) - и пишем свой пример. Несколько ограниченный, по функционалу, но для показа кода хватит. Если местный механизм не позволяет показать пример в полном объеме, то тогда уже можно и ссылку на jsfiddle привести.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('селктор-для-ссылки').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var v = $('селктор-для-инпута').val()
    window.location.href = 'php.php?id=' + v

})
```

Что-то в таком духе. Но, я уверен, ты хотел сделать иначе - повесить обработчик на изменение инпута, который подменяет href в ссылке. Это будет сделать сложнее, потому что обработчик на изменение инпута - это уродский код. Ведь он меняется и при нажатии бэкспейса и при нажатии на буквы-цифры и при ctrl+v. Нативной поддержки, по-моему нет нормальной.

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Вот, почитай про селекторы, лучше использовать id.

На чистом JS твоя ZZZ будет вглядеть примерно так:

```
function ZZZ() {
    var el = document.getElementById('id-инпута')
    var v = el.value
    window.location.href = '/php.php?id=' + v
    return false
}
```

Comment: а как еще можно передать значение из инпута в ссылку? На мой взгляд javascript - это лучший способ. Вечерком проверю, если сработает - очень хорошо будет.

Comment: только JS-ом и можно, по-другому никак.

Answer (score 3):

> То есть человек пишет слово в поле, например "Праздник". Затем жмет на ссылку и его переводит по ссылке на страницу php.php?id=Праздник

Очень похоже на то, что вам просто нужно передать GET-ом какие-то данные с формы

JS здесь не нужен также, как и ссылка, нужна кнопка :)

```html
<form method="GET" action="php.php" target="_blank">
  <input type="text" name="id" />
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>

<!-- seee more here http://jsfiddle.net/ua9csb6t/ -->
```

Как это работает:

1. у формы есть атрибут action - в нём указывается куда необходимо передать данные
2. Данными для формы явзяются все input, textarea, select html-контролы
3. чтобы в php.php передать по ключу id какие-то данные - необходимо создать форму с соответствующим action и разместить в ней поле с атрибутом name=id (собственно как в коде выше)

[вот рабочий пример](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ua9csb6t/show/)

---

PS: для передачи данных формы лучше использовать POST

см. для справки [HTTP Methods: GET vs. POST](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Comment: Нет, вопрос задан корректно, необходимо было передать данные именно в ссылку. Но спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 2):

`onClick` юзать противопоказано вообще всем адекватным кодерам.
Всё гениальное просто:

```js
function listen(e){
  this.href = 'php.php?id=' + encodeURIComponent(document.querySelector('#toLink').value); // Устанавливаем значение из input[type='text']
  // For Example [start]
  document.querySelector('#preview').innerHTML = 'Я перехожу сюда: <strong>' + this.href + '</strong>';
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector('#preview').innerHTML = '';
  }, 1000);
  e.preventDefault(); // Пока эта строка есть, перехода не будет. Уберёшь - переход произойдёт
  // For Example [end]
}

document.querySelector('#link').addEventListener('click', listen);
```

```css
a{
  color: #30a7fc;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
Введите адрес: <input type='text' id='toLink' /><br />
<a href='#' id='link'>Перейти</a><br />

<!-- For Example -->
<span id='preview'>&nbsp;</span>
```

Примеры можно выкинуть :)

Comment: уже не в первый раз с Вами советуюсь! Ух, крутой вы чел)

Comment: @anj1817, Я аж покраснел, благодарю :)